# SharePoint visual webpart unit testing in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing, sharepoint-2013

I need to know whether we can create test cases for custom webparts that are build for SharePoint web applications. I have created custom webpart for my SharePoint list with asp.net controls (asp:textbox, asp:dropdown etc..) and added functions like populating dropdown in page_load, used spquery for querying items and displayed in asp gridview

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
   {
     // Check new or edit item and populate saved values in controls on edit item
    }
}

Protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Action done on save click
}
```

I have used Nunit for creating unit test cases for console applications in development phase. It is very useful for me to cover all test cases also reduces testing phase time and bugs.

But I don't know how to implement unit testing in webparts page load function, button click actions etc..

I am new to SharePoint as well as Unit testing. It will be very greatful, if someone help me to handle this by providing some examples for the above cases.